# How can I make an Electron application to send it to others?

Tags: electron

I have an Electron installed. I have html, js and package.json files. I open Electron, I transfer my html file there, the application is launched. And now what? How can I show my app to my friend? "Install the electron, so I threw you the files, open the electron, put the file with the extension .html in the special window, see what a beautiful application I have." How can I do better? How to make it so that I would throw off a friend, well, maybe a folder, but that there would have to open 1 file to run my application?

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-distribution.md Or this: http://electron.rocks/distributing-electron-apps/

Comment: @Rup Yes, mabe.... But is is really hard for me even with the instruction.

Comment: But I have understood it.